# Why is it not displaying the exact string I typed when it is not 10 letter word?

Tags: string, assembly, tasm

im using tasm 1.4 assembly language. This really bugs me, whenever I accept 10 maximum letter word, if the user typed only 5 letter, nothing will displayed on screen. But when the user typed 6 letter word like "aaaaaa" the output will be "    aa". There is 4 spaces at the beginning. if the user typed 8 letter word like "aaaaaaaa", the output will be "  aaaaaa". Lastly, but if the user typed 10 letter word like "aaaaaaaaaa", the output will be the same.

The question is, why is there spaces at the beginning if the user input less than 10 letter word?

```
.model small
.stack 120h
.data

aname label byte
asize db 11
aactual db ?
atext db 11 dup (" "),"$"

ent db 13,10, "Enter a 10 letter word: $"

.code

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ax,03
int 10h

;displaying the prompt message
mov ah,09
lea dx,ent
int 21h


;accepting input strings
mov ah,10
lea dx,aname
int 21h

;moving the text below to so that it dont overlap with the prompt message
mov ah,02
mov bx,0
mov dl,0
mov dh,2
int 10h

;displaying the user input
mov ah,09
lea dx,atext
int 21h


mov ah,4ch
int 21h

end
```

Comment: 21/9 needs a "$" at the end of the string, this is not added by 21/a

Comment: @Tommylee2k he has the `$` at the end of the buffer.

Comment: the dup'ed blanks in the input buffer override your entry. so "aaaaaa<cr><sp><sp><sp><sp>" will be displayed as "<sp><sp><sp><sp>aa". to verify: replace the " " in the dup with something else, you will find it "over" your entered string

Comment: @Tommylee2k what does <cr> means? and any solution to this? so that even the user input 6 strings, the output will be the same?

Comment: @Tommylee2k care to explain? How could an assembly time space fill override the run-time entry?

Comment: <cr> = carriage return. when you type "enter" to finish your string, it's stored in the buffer, together behind the string

Comment: @jester it's overriding the output, not the code. "aaaaa<cr>xxxx" would show as "xxxxa" on the screen. even if all 10 char were written, there's no <lf> in the buffer

Comment: @Tommylee2k sooo, any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: @Tommylee2k if it is overriding the output, where do other output go? such as "aaaaa<cr>xxxx" -> "xxxxa" where did the other 4 "a" go?

Comment: you could use aactual to place the "$" to the end of the entry

Comment: @Tommylee2k how do I do that?

Comment: It prints the `aaaaa` first, then it prints the <cr> which moves the cursor back to the start of the line, and then prints the remaining spaces which erase the things already printed. You can do e.g. `movzx bx, aactual; mov byte ptr [atext+bx], '$'` or similar.

Comment: @Jester exactly. those 4 "a" disappear "under" the "x"es

Comment: @Jester tbh i am a total noob at this language. can you please code it inside my code specifically?